# Carousel from Bootstrap does not work on my site

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm having this weird problem with Bootstrap framework. I decided to test the Carousel feature and I deployed it here: http://tworkimariolki.pl/beta/item.html

As you can see the slide show does not "move on" and the clicks aren't working either. But the very weird thing is that if I try to test it on `bootply.com` it works perfectly! Link: http://www.bootply.com/CRuiNa8shS

Can you guys explain to me why is this happening?

Answer (score 4):

Well, the console says it all:

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
```

Change the order of the script files in your `head` element so jQuery is loaded before `bootstrap.js`:

```
<head>
    <link href="../bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="../bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

Comment: Well I do have jquery included: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yes, but jQuery needs to be loaded before scripts that depend om jQuery (e.g. `bootstrap.js`).

Comment: Yes, as I wrote below I've figure it out - thank you for your help :)

Comment: Ok, you don´t need to post that answer though.